# mvc attribute based route with an optional first parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have this route: [Route("{country?}/mymessages")]

When I request http://allthings.trade/australia/mymessages the route works fine. If I try:http://allthings.trade/mymessages the route is not hit.

I thought it might be the middle "/" so I change the route to the below and it made no difference:
[Route("{country?}mymessages")]

Any ideas, I suspect the first parameter can not be optional maybe?

Thanks Guys.

Answer (score 0):

I would think that it might just be that you cannot have optional paramaters in the middle of a route. I could be wrong though.

Why not just have two routes?

```
[Route("{country}/mymessages")]
[Route("mymessages")]
public ActionResult MyAction(string country, string message){..}
```

EDIT:
I just attempted to run in locally, couldn't though as I can't even get yours to work, more code?